# What happens when I close() a file descriptor?

Tags: linux, open-files, file-descriptors

I am trying to get the whole picture with file descriptors. Say I have process1 which initially has these file descriptors:

```
 _process1_
|          |
| 0 stdin  |
| 1 stdout |
| 2 stderr |
|__________|
```

Then I close file descriptor 1:

```
close(1);
```

The file descriptor 1 translates(points) to the stdout *FILE structure* in the kernel's *Open Files Table*.

With the code above the file descriptor 1 gets deleted from the process's table which becomes:

```
 _process1_
|          |
| 0 stdin  |
| 2 stderr |
|__________|
```

But what happens in the kernel? Does the `stdout` FILE structure get deallocated? How is that possible if stdout is a special file (the monitor) and probably being used by other processes? What about FILE structures that are just normal files (.txt for example)? What if such a file is being used by an other process?

Answer (score 19):

> The file descriptor 1 translates to the stdout FILE structure in the Kernel's Open Files Table.

This is a misunderstanding. The kernel's file table has nothing whatsoever to do with user-space file structures.

In any event, the kernel has two levels of indirection. There is the internal structure that represents the file itself, which is reference counted. There is an "open file description" that is reference counted. And then there is the file handle, which is not reference counted. The file structure points the way to the inode itself. The open file description contains things like the open mode and file pointer.

When you call close, you always close the file handle. When a file handle is closed, the reference count on its open file description is decremented. If it goes to zero, the open file description is also released and the reference count on the file itself is decremented. Only if that goes to zero is the kernel's file structure freed.

There is no chance for one process to release a resource another process is using because shared resources are reference counted.

Comment: I have a slight difficulty with the understanding of the terminology in your answer. I am guessing that file pointer means "file offset". Is that what you meant? Also what you meant by *file handle*?

Comment: That's correct, by "file offset", I mean the offset at which a subsequent read or write would occur. A "file handle" is a link between a process and an open file description -- it's what you get back when `open` succeeds.

Answer (score 5):

In this case not a lot will happen.  stdin, stdout, and stderr all tend to be clones of the same file descriptor.  The reference counter for the file descriptor will be decremented by one.  The same file descriptor is usually held by the shell from which the program was run, so the file descriptor needs to be kept.

The kernel keeps reference counts for all files (inodes) that are open.  As long as the reference count is greater than zero the file will be kept.  I would expect a separate counter is kept for open file handles.  Once this hits zero the kernel can release the memory used by the file handle.

When all references to the file (directory entries and file handles) have been removed, the file system code will mark the inode for reuse.  Any blocks the file has are made available for allocation.  Many file systems will clear the block pointers in the inode when it is released.  This makes recovering a deleted file difficult.  Updates to disk may be buffered and completed at a later time.

Comment: Two questions: (1) are the file descriptors really ref-counted?  When you control-d a `cat > some.file`, cat gets an EOF on stdin, but the shell does not. (2) Why reference counting? Why not some form of garbage collection? Isn't GC far better in user space?

Comment: Expanding on BillThor's answer: In normal cases stdin, stdout, and stderr are just open file handles to a TTY device. So if you close the file handle, that TTY device is still there, and can even be re-opened again at a later time.

Comment: @BruceEdiger: (1) when the shell runs `cat > some.file` what its actually doing is forking, opening up 'some.file' and assigning it to file descriptor 1, then it does `exec("cat")`. When a process is exec()'d, it inherits the open file descriptors.

Comment: @BruceEdiger (2) Reference counting is a perfectly fine form of garbage collection when it's used on data structures that do not contain pointers to (or chains of pointers ending in) other data structures of the same type. Also, this is happening in kernel space (not that it matters very much).

Answer (score 0):

Your description is correct up to the last paragraph.

> But what happens in the kernel? Does the stdout FILE structure get deallocated? How is that possible if stdout is a special file (the monitor) and probably being used by other processes? What about FILE structures that are just normal files (`afile.txt` for example)? What if such a file is being used by an other process?

Except that the kernel knows nothing of stdin/stdout/stderr. These are just files descriptors 0,1, and 2. It is a convention as to what they are used for.

Not for the last paragraph. The terminal window is save. Deleting a file descriptor is not deleting a file. Even `rm` only removes a directory entry, it does not delete files (see reference counting in other answers: when nothing references it, then the file is deleted). Therefore a file is deleted when it has no directory entries, and it is not opened by ANY process.